# How to set-up nest template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm currently working on a C++ project with templated classes. I've done it before and I know how templating works for single-level template parameters. But for the classes in my current project I use the following (**important note:** heavily simplified for reading purposes)

```
template<typename T>
struct B{
    B(){}
    void bar();
};

template<int k>
struct A{
    A(){}
    void foo(); 
};

template class A<1>;
template class B< A<1> >;
```

which compiles and runs fine, as long as I don't invoke foo() or bar(). Now, I know how to write the template for void foo() for all k by using

```
template<int k>
void A<k>::foo(){
    printf("foo %d\n", k);
}
```

And I know I can put

```
template<>
void B<A<1> >::bar(){
    printf("A<1> bar\n");
}
```

which will implement bar() for B < A<1> >. Here is the thing: I want to use multiple values for k (the k=1 is just an example) without having to copy the above for all cases. That's why I want to write a template for bar() also. However,

```
template<int k>
void B<A<k> >::bar(){
    printf("Templated bar() for k=%d\n", k);
}
```

does not work. What has to be the exact template statement to template bar() for any B < A >? Classes A and B in this case were delivered in a library (header) I'm not allowed to change and with foo() and bar() left to be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You can partially specialise `B` like so:

```
// this is unchanged
template<typename T>
struct B{
    B(){}
    void bar();
};

// but this is added by you
template <int k>
struct B<A<k>> {
    void bar();
};
```

which will enable you to implement:

```
template <int k>
void B<A<k>>::bar() {
    printf("A<k> bar\n");
}
```

and run:

```
int main() {
    B<A<3>> b{};

    b.bar();
}
```

Comment: Worth mentioning a further generalization: `template<template <int> class T, int k > struct B< T<k> >{void bar(){printf("bar %d\n", k);}};`

Answer (score 1):

Partial specialization is fine (as mentioned by others), but you have to implement all members from the original class `B`. Another approach is to extract `k` from `A` using an external tool (`A_traits` in this example).

```
template <typename>
struct A_traits;

template <int K>
struct A_traits<A<K>> : std::integral_constant<int, K> {};
```

Your implementation is nearly unchanged, simply use `A_traits` to extract `k`.

```
template <typename T>
void B<T>::bar() {
  printf("Templated bar() for k=%d\n", A_traits<T>::value);
}
```